# How to use the Auth Component of CakePHP 2.2+ only using the username field?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm developing a Controller that manages two kind of Login:

1. Email and Password
2. Email

the second type only has the email field. The reason is that a third party provider gives me the email of the user that is logged but I also need to check if that email exists in my database.

So I have two type of authentications, the question is:

Can I use Auth for the second type? (only email check)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I dont see the reason to use Auth here (you are abusing the whole Auth mechanism with this approach. it is also just a huge overhead to handle a simple lookup).
just use find(first) to check if the email exists and use the result accordingly. thats all there is to it.

Comment: thank you for your advice...yes, i think you are right, but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in this link:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

```
<?php
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This for me works fine for you!

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I think it customizes the 'username' field, the password field is NOT overridden... no?

Comment: The password field is required for the authorization for me.

Comment: so what do to? can I use only one field or do i have to write a custom function that find() the single field ?

Comment: You have to write a custom function

Answer (score 0):

read this

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

try this:-

```
<?php
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'users'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);

?>
```

Or

```
<?php
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: excuse me, but reading _findUser method i found that the password is required, so I think that using 'username' => 'email' does not override the fields list, because 'password' still here....no ?